# Как вывести массив в три колонки?

Tags: php, html, css

Есть массив, который сдержит HTML код.
Формируется массив следующим кодом:

```
$html=array();
for ($l = 0; $l < count($ukanal1[1]); $l++) { 
  $html[$l]='<TABLE BORDER=0> <TD width=100%><TR><TD width=100%>
  <a href=admin.php?mod=tv&id='.$ukanal1[1][$l].' > '.$ukanal1[2][$l].'</a>
  </TD> <TD width=20px align="right">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="check_del[]" value="'.$ukanal1[1][$l].'">
  </TD></TR></TABLE>';
  }
```

Собственно вопрос: как вывести этот массив в три колонки? Пробовал с помощью СSS.
Вот так:

```
 <style>
   .book {
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Для Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Для Safari и Chrome */
    column-count: 3;
    margin: 0px auto; 
    width: 90%; 
   }
   </style>
```

Но почему-то съезжают строки:

[image]

Как еще можно корректно отобразить массив в три колонки?

Подсказали банально, разбить массив на три части и впихнуть в три колонки (ячейки таблицы)...
ну разбил я длину массива на три

PHP код:

```
$colum  = round( count($html) / 3);
```

А дальше как?

Прошу прощения, может вопрос и банальный... Просто уже пол дня ищу решение...

Comment: Почему бы сразу не выводить в три колонки, еще на этапе формирования?

Comment: эмм.... как? можно поподробнеЙ?

Comment: Я не Ванга, но у вас же тег table не закрыт. Тег tr внутри td. Это просто ночной кошмар табличных верстальщиков.

Вот [тут][1] смотрите как работать с таблицами.


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/html/table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//variant 1. Читаем сначала первую колонку, потом вторую итп:

[array_slice](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php) - разбиваете массив на нужное количество массива.
Запускаете цикл с количеством итераций, равном длине наибольшей 
колонки.
На каждой итерации запускаете внутренний цикл, достающий при помощи 
[array_shift](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php) верхний(начальный) элемент каждой части массива и
запихивающий в соответствующую ячейку таблицы.

Таблица при этом формируется все равно построчно.

//variant2:
Читаем построчно:

построчно формируете таблицу, склеивая при помощи implode кусочки массива, длиной, равной
числу столбцов. Кусочки извлекаете при помощи array_slice.

Answer (score 2):

Привожу код, который я использую. Разбиение на 4 столбца. Думаю, понятно. Если нет, разъясню.

**PHP:**

```
<div class="fl_n gen_tags_block">
<?
    $tags=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_tags;");
    $TagsCount=mysql_num_rows($tags);
    $TagRows=ceil($TagsCount/4);
    for($column=0,$i=0;$column<4;$column++)
    {
        echo '<div class="fl_l" style="width:24%">';
        for($j=0;$j<$TagRows&&$i<$TagsCount;$j++,$i++) 
        {
            $TagID=mysql_result($tags,$i,'id');
            $TagValue=mysql_result($tags,$i,'value');
            if($j) echo '<br>'; 
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="'.$TagID.'" id="'.$TagValue.'"> '.$TagValue;
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fl_r { float:right; }
.fl_l { float:left; }
.fl_n { overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы Вам просто не использовать циклы для вывода? 
Правда если делать через такие циклы, то потребуется их 2 (вложенных). А это, насколько я знаю, грузит систему. Я так и не выучил как рассчитывать сложность.
Если требуется подсказать, как это сделать - могу написать сюда же.

```
$A = array();

for ($i=1; $i <('количество элементов'); $i++) {
    for ($j=1, $j=3, $j++) {
    echo $a[$i]."   ";
    }
echo "<br>"

}
```

Если Вам это нужно, можно легко вывести таблицей.

Comment: думаю если напишите то это будет только плюс... зарание спасибо...

Comment: обновил пост

Answer (score 0):

Как подметил evlanoff (18 часов назад), разъезжается из-за вот этого раздолбайства:

```
<TD width=100%><TR><TD width=100%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот простое решение вывести массив в три колонки при помощи CSS [Ссылка Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RustemS/pyzex2ju/)

```
.col3 ul{
list-style-position: inside;
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;
list-style-type:none;
height:150px;
}
```